# I've tried to use this python package I installed but I get this error

Tags: python, pip

I installed this package recently called `pyinstaller` I went to use it and when I did it popped up with this error

```
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I used `pip install pyinstaller` to install it. Is there any way I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install it like this:

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
```

(make sure that your python and pip are in PATH)

To check if pyinstaller got installed correctly, type `pyinstaller` in your cmd/terminal, if no errors appear, it means you have pyinstaller installed.

Also, you have to modify your User PATH environment variable to include `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts`.

(Look [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) if you need help doing that.)

Comment: thank you dude its working perfectly now

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `python3 -m pip [package name]`

Comment: You should explain why this might be necessary.  Otherwise, this is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Managed to recreate the same issue on my laptop.
For me the issue was that pip didn't have proper rights to install corectly.
Uninstalling pyinstaller and installing again with cmd as admin worked.